# trying to access data which is inside a specific iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

im trying to access data which is inside an iframe. There are multiple iframes on the web pages without ID tag, source of the iframe is given in html format , no external link given.
 so can i switch to a particular iframe and access data inside it ??

i tried using

```
var ifrm = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[1]; 
var $iFrameContents = $('ifrm').contents();
$entryContent   = $iFrameContents.find('div.entry-content');
```

but this code is NOT working.  i have attached a screenshot of my coding , can anyone help me in writing a javascript/jquery to get the data in Tag  inside an iframe with index [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZhUW.png) . 
[screenshot of coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZhUW.png)

Comment: Hi. Jeeven, don't give up just yet. Try looking around the web some other approaches. Do you have access to the code in the iframe?

Comment: `but this code is NOT working` - where does it break first?

Comment: you do realise `var ifrm` will be the second iframe on the page ... and `$('ifrm')` has nothing to do with that var, right? because the string `'ifrm'` is completely unrelated to the content of var `ifrm` ... try `$(ifrm)` instead

Comment: $ifrm = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[2].contentWindow.document;    i tried usung this function, ended up with error "Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object "

Answer (score 0):

`iframe.contentWindow` is its internal window, and `iframe.contentWindow.document` is its internal document object.

But bear in mind that iframes are subject to cross-origin rules, and you won't even be able to read the URL of the iframe if it's on a different origin. You can start with a link to same-origin, but the user could navigate it elsewhere.

[window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) can be used to communicate between windows on different origins, if you have control of both.

Comment: $ifrm = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[2].contentWindow.doc‌​ument; i tried usung this function, ended up with error "Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object "